# React Redux how can I fire an async fetch request to the backend after a dispatch changed the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a React Redux Toolkit slice where I want to:

1. Update my state
2. Fetch this updated state to my backend

I would like to do something like this:

```js
const sendStateToBackend = createAsyncThunk(
    '.../sendStateToBackend',
    async (state) => {
        const data = await ...
    }
)


createSlice({
    ...,
    reducers: {
        addTodo:(state, action) => {
            state.todos.push(action.payload)
            dispatch(sendStateToBackend(state)) // This is an Anti pattern???
        }
    },
    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder.addCase(sendStateToBackend.pending, (state) => {
            state.isLoading = true
        }

        builder.addCase(sendStateToBackend.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false
        }
    }
})
```

In my page.tsx:

```js
const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    try {
        dispatch(addTodo(values))
        // Can I trigger another dispatch here? 
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred while submitting the form: ', error)
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `extraReducers` section of your Redux Toolkit slice to handle the API call triggered by the `addTodo` action. Instead of dispatching the `sendStateToBackend` action inside the `addTodo` reducer, you should let the `extraReducers` handle it when the `addTodo` action is fulfilled.

Here's how you can refactor your code:

1- Remove the dispatch from the `addTodo` reducer in the slice:

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const sendStateToBackend = createAsyncThunk('.../sendStateToBackend', async (state) => {
  // Implement your API call here and return the response data
  // For example, you might use fetch or axios to send the state to the backend
  // const response = await fetch('your-api-url', {
  //   method: 'POST',
  //   body: JSON.stringify(state),
  //   headers: {
  //     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  //   },
  // });
  // const data = await response.json();
  // return data;
});

const todoSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todo',
  initialState: { todos: [], isLoading: false },
  reducers: {
    addTodo: (state, action) => {
      state.todos.push(action.payload);
    },
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(sendStateToBackend.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(sendStateToBackend.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        // Do something with the response data from the backend if needed
        // const responseData = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export const { addTodo } = todoSlice.actions;
export default todoSlice.reducer;
```

2- In your page.tsx, you can dispatch both actions sequentially inside the "onSubmit" function:

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { addTodo, sendStateToBackend } from './your-todo-slice';

const YourPageComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    try {
      // Dispatch the addTodo action to update the state
      dispatch(addTodo(values));

      // Dispatch the sendStateToBackend action to send the updated state to the backend
      await dispatch(sendStateToBackend(values));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('An error occurred while submitting the form: ', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Your page content */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourPageComponent;
```

when the `addTodo` action is dispatched, it will update the state in the Redux store. Then, the `extraReducers` section will handle the `sendStateToBackend` action, making the API call to send the updated state to the backend when the `addTodo` action is fulfilled. By using `await` in the `onSubmit` function, you can ensure that the API call is completed before continuing with the rest of the code.